# Python import pyLDAvis module - DeprecationWarning

Tags: python, scikit-learn, visualization, lda, topic-modeling

I try to visualize my topic modeling results with the pyLDAvis python module. But when i try to import:

```
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.sklearn
```

Then i get the following warnings:

```
...\site-packages\msgpack_numpy.py:77: DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring 
is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs.
Use frombuffer instead dtype=np.dtype(descr)).reshape(obj[b'shape'])
```

A lot of these warnings results, always in the same file.. Does somebody know, how I could fix this? Thanks!